# How to make table equally spaced and wrap word

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I'm using twitter bootstrap, but I think it has nothing to do with the solution, so here is the code:

```
div.span12
   table.table.table-hover
      thead
        tr
            th Device Name
            th Device ID
            th Device Description
      tbody
        each dev in devices
            tr
                td #{dev.dname}
                td #{dev.did}
                td #{dev.ddesc}
```

If one of the attributes gets too big,  the table shifts to one side allowing space for the big item. How can I keep the original even spacing and allow word wrap on the rows of the table?

```
 <div class="span12">
   <table class="table table-hover">
       <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Device Name</th>
             <th>Device ID</th>
             <th>Device Description</th>
         </tr></thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>nn</td>
                <td>ii</td>
                <td>dd</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: Please provide generated HTML, the template code is useless to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override properties for `td`

```
td {
   width: 33.33%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TTjrg/)**